# Negative acknowledge rabbitmq message which are consumed using AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, rabbitmq

I am consuming a rabbitmq queue using AWS lambda. I want it to be sent to the dead letter exchange(DLX) in case of an error while processing the message. The rabbitmq currently only sends the message to Rabbitmq Dead-Letter-Exchange based on the below criteria

1. Negative acknowledgment
2. Passed TTL for the queue
3. Exceeded queue length

I want to send it to DLX based on negative acknowledgment rather than TTL. Is there any way to achieve this from AWS Lambda?